# SharedPreferences and int

Tags: java, android

I'm fairly new to JAVA and Android Studio. I've come across an issue regarding the SharedPreferences API, and I'm having troubles saving int values in my KEYS.

So, basically I'm requesting DAY_OF_YEAR from a Calendar object, which is an int, then I want to store that int into the SharedPreferences, and pass it to a second activity with intent, but when I request that value in the second activity, it always returns null.

```
private SharedPreferences mPreferences;
private int SAVED_DAY_VALUE;
private int mCurrentDayNumber;
private int mDayState;
```

The OnCreate :

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
mDayCurrentNumber = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);

// Both lines ask SAVED_DAY_VALUE to be String
mDayState = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).getInt(SAVED_DAY_VALUE, 0);
mPreferences.edit().putInt(SAVED_DAY_VALUE, mCurrentDayNumber);

mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent secondActivityIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            secondActivityIntent.putExtra("PassDay", mDayState);
```

I think my variables are messed up. Thanks for helping a newbie like me.

Comment: calling `commit` or `apply` ?

Comment: Oh right thanks, I forgot the .apply() method :(

Comment: It sounds like you're storing the value only to be able to access it in the second activity. If that's true, than notice that it's actually enough passing the value via Intent, and using getIntent() in the second activity to get the value. SharedPreferences are not meant as temporary storage to pass data between components, but to store values persistently.

Comment: I actually need both. I need my app to be able to remember the DAY_OF_YEAR after first launch, and the intent was just a test to check if the values were actually passing to my SecondActivity, because I'll need them to display informations there, depending of the day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [this tutorial](https://www.journaldev.com/9412/android-shared-preferences-example-tutorial).

Basically, when you save data into SharedPreferences you need key and the actual data. The key is always string and it is used just to access the data.

For example let put some int into SharedPreferences and then acces it.

**Storing data**

For storing data you should first initialize SharedPreferences

```
SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0); 
Editor editor = pref.edit();
```

Then in the editor we put our data (first parameter is the key and second parametar is the actual data)

```
editor.putInt("SAVED_DAY_VALUE", mCurrentDayNumber)
editor.commit();
```

**Retrieve data**

For retrieving the data you just call

```
pref.getInt("SAVED_DAY_VALUE", 0);
```

Where 0 is the default value if the key "SAVED_DAY_VALUE" is not found.

Hope it helps and welcome to Android :)

Comment: Thank you very much sir. I obviously forgot the .apply() method. Helped me a lot :)

Comment: Any time sir :)

Answer (score 0):

`getInt()` and `putInt()` both has first parameter `key` and key should be string, but you have defined `SAVE_DAY_VALUE` an int.

So it should be a `String` something like `String SAVE_DAY_KEY = "currentDay"`

Comment: Yeah thanks a lot, I think I understand what's wrong with my keys.